# Encrypting files securely using user supplied password

Tags: encryption, aes, file-encryption, pbkdf2

I'm currently trying to build a (sort of) secure, desktop based RTF text editor written for node-webkit using node.js. Based on some answers that I read here, such as [How can I securely convert a "string" password to a key used in AES?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38828/how-can-i-securely-convert-a-string-password-to-a-key-used-in-aes) and [Recommended # of iterations when using PKBDF2-SHA256?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256), amongst others, I've come up with the following system. However, I'm rather unsure about the manner in which I've combined these algorithms, and I was hoping someone could check the system.

On first time application initialization:

1. Generate 1024 cryptographically secure pseudorandom bytes (`k`)
2. Generate 256 more ^ as a salt (`s`)
3. Ask for user password (`p`)
4. Stretch p using PBKDF-2 using s as salt, 64K rounds (n = number of rounds) to a length of 512 bytes (length = l) (`P`) (takes a little over a second on my system)
5. Encrypt k using AES-CBC with P as key (`K`)
6. Store `s||n||l||K` on disk

For encrypting and then saving a new file:

1. Ask for user password (`p`)
2. Read `s||n||l||K` from disk
3. As in step 3 above, stretch `p` to `P` using `s`, `n` and `l` from step 2
4. Decrypt `K` using `P`
5. Use `k` to encrypt file data using AES CBC; save to disk

Possible concerns (keeping in mind that this is supposed to be usable on a modern laptop/desktop) include:

- magic numbers (64K, 512, 1024)
- no IV (not sure if it's necessary)
- something about some combination of algorithms
- some other stupid mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My observations are as follows:

- Storing the value of `l` is pointless. You should store `n` instead. You should be aware that PBKDF2 doesn't produce different sequences for different values of `l`, but rather extends the sequence longer.
- Generating 1024 bytes for `k` and 512 bytes for `P` seems odd, since AES accepts no larger than a 256-bit (32 byte) key.
- In step 5 of the encryption, you say that `k` is encrypted using AES-CBC, but do not mention how the IV is selected. This isn't hugely important here, since `k` won't have duplicate blocks, but it's good practice to use the cipher mode properly.
- In step 5 of the decryption, you again mention AES-CBC without specifying the IV. This is critical - improperly selecting the IV may completely break the system.
- You provide no authenticity on the file or the stored metadata. This is actually important, because AES-CBC is malleable (i.e. ciphertext can be modified in ways that affect the plaintext, without needing to know the key) and your construction could be particularly susceptible.

Your general construction is actually alright, but it's missing the details that separate a secure construction from a weak one.

Here's how I'd do it:

- let *p* be the user's password.
- let *k<sub>d</sub>* (data key) be a random 128-bit value.
- let *s* (salt) be a random be a random 128-bit value.
- let *c* be the iteration count, e.g. 1,000,000.
- let *k<sub>m</sub>* (master key) and *k<sub>a</sub>* (authenticity key) be computed as two 16 byte (128-bit) halves of *PBKDF2(p, s, c, 32)*, i.e. PBKDF2 of the user password and salt, with the defined iteration count, and an output length of 32 bytes.
- let *k'<sub>d</sub>* (encrypted data key) be computed as *AES(k<sub>d</sub>, k<sub>m</sub>)*, using 128-bit AES in ECB mode.
- let *IV* be the initialisation vector for use when encrypting the file data.
- let *Q* (metadata) be the concatenated values *s | c | k'<sub>d</sub> | IV*.
- let *a<sub>Q</sub>* be the authenticity record for *Q*, defined as *H(Q, k<sub>a</sub>)*, where *H* is a cryptographic hash function in a HMAC construction, e.g. HMAC-SHA256.
- store *Q* and *a<sub>Q</sub>* in the file header.

Since 128-bit keys are being used, and AES has a block size of 128 bits, only one block need be encrypted when computing *k'<sub>d</sub>* and therefore AES in ECB mode is safe; the additional complexity of using CBC or another mode is unnecessary.

Providing an authenticity record for the metadata helps prevent an attacker from "tweaking" the parameters needed to decrypt the file. Most critically, it provides authenticity of the IV, which is a prime target for modification as xor'ing it with a value will result in the first block of plaintext also being xor'ed with that value upon decryption. This property is known as malleability. For partially known (e.g. structured) plaintexts, this can have devastating effects.

You should be able to extrapolate the rest of the file encryption and decryption process from here. One addition I would make is to compute a HMAC hash of the encrypted data, then store that in the header, to ensure authenticity of the encrypted data.

Comment: Firstly, why use only 128 bit keys? For the convenience of using ECB mode?

Comment: @VivekGhaisas Yes, though convenience isn't really the term I'd use. The security margin of 256-bit keys vs. the security margin of 128-bit keys, at current, is not significant enough to make an impact on your design. Using CBC or CTR mode requires that you add additional complexity, which increases the potential for bugs and design flaws. Sticking with ECB against a 128-bit key in this very specific case is, somewhat counter-intuitively, a likely safer option.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, because [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb) suggests that I shouldn't be using ECB. Or does AES-ECB take care of that?

Comment: Oh, the key is only one block, so ECB is safe. For the message, use an IV and CBC, am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Take a look at some of the CBC-related vulnerabilities there have been in OpenSSL. Initialization vector is important for algorithms that use cipher block chaining. For example, see these explanations: 
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/how-can-cipher-block-chaining-cbc-in-ssl-be-attacked
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25844/attacking-cbc-with-predictable-but-encrypted-iv